# performSegueWithIdentifier opens a new window in OS X

Tags: macos, storyboard

I am working on OS X application using Storyboard.

I have 2 view controllers LaunchViewController and MainViewController. WindowController has LaunchViewController as window content. LaunchViewController does some checks  and then segues to MainViewController. I would expect to show MainViewController in first Window but instead I see 2 windows one showing LaunchViewController and other using MainViewController.

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSegueToContentView sender:self];`

Is this expected behaviour? Should I use ContainerView instead of calling performSegue?

Answer (score 1):

I advise using a custom segue in order to avoid opening new view controllers in a new window.

[This Code example](https://github.com/foundry/NSViewControllerPresentation) may help you...